# How to configure nutch in eclipse?

Tags: linux, eclipse, nutch

I am trying to configure the environment so that I can test and run the latest trunk of nutch but nothing happens. My OS is Ubuntu 12.04, Java IDE Eclipse 3.7 Indigo and all the plugins that are required to run nutch. I will be grateful to give me links with detailed tutorials how to do it. I tried with this link: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse but I could not do it. Hope there are other sources where I can find proper instructions how to run nutch under Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions in that link and succeeded. The problem could be **Eclipse** version, try with [**Eclipse for Java EE Developers**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2).

Add these jars to your **trunk project** as external jar files : **cyberneko.jar**, **rome-0.9.jar** and **tagsoup-1.2.jar**. You can find all these jars by a simple **google** search.

Comment: It was enough to add rome-0.9.jar and the project was built successfully. It looks like I did not add proper jars to the project. 10x for your answer.

Comment: Sometimes trunk is built and runs, but it may not work properly. Try to get over all "X"s in the project.